# Unable to locate package ros-indigo-barrett-hand

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im trying to control the Barrett Hand using ROS. I'm trying to install the packages, but im getting the error when ever i try it.

" Unable to locate package ros-indigo-barrett-hand"

Can someone help me solving this issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207820/unable-to-locate-package-ros-indigo-barrett-hand/) by [krishna43](https://answers.ros.org/users/22267/krishna43/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2015-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That package has not been released in Indigo. I first checked this by running `apt-cache search barrett-hand` and saw no results. Then I navigated to this link: http://www.ros.org/debbuild/indigo.html?q=barret_hand and verified that it has not been built for Indigo. As a side note, it is available on Hydro: http://www.ros.org/debbuild/hydro.html?q=barrett_hand

This means you need to install the package from source. Clone the repository to your workspace's `src/` directory, and then run `catkin_make` in the root of your workspace to try and build the package. According to the [package's documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/barrett_hand#Dependencies), you also need to have the `pcan_python` package installed.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2015-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [krishna43](https://answers.ros.org/users/22267/krishna43/) on 2015-04-24**:
Can you guide me how to install from source?
I'm new th ROS and Ubuntu. I dont have any idea how to do it.

**Comment by [tanghz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21137/tanghz/) on 2015-04-27**:
I think you've already created a workspace, if not, see [this](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace). Then download the package:[link text](https://github.com/RobotnikAutomation/barrett_hand). and expand it to :~/catkin_ws/src, then: $ cd catkin_ws; $ catkin_make.

**Comment by [tanghz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21137/tanghz/) on 2015-04-27**:
but I find that this package has no indigo level...

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-04-27**:
I'm guessing it will build fine on the hydro branch.

**Comment by [krishna43](https://answers.ros.org/users/22267/krishna43/) on 2015-04-29**:
Thanks for your response. i install the barrett hand packages, but still im getting the error; this is the error. can you help me with this?

[bhand_controller.launch] is neither a launch file in package [bhand_controller] nor is [bhand_controller] a launch file name

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-04-29**:
Are you sure that you have properly sourced the workspace that the barrett-hand package was built in?

**Comment by [krishna43](https://answers.ros.org/users/22267/krishna43/) on 2015-05-01**:
oh! i didn't. thanks it's working now.

And, i have another doubt, Can i control the barrett hand by writing a python script and move it to the position i give in the python script?